# Get variable in javascript from aspx.cs

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an aspx form called MyForm.aspx. In this form I had included a javascript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/MyForm.js"></script>
```

In MyForm.aspx.cs a have a property:

```
public string Username { get; set; }
```

How can I access this `Username` variable in the MyForm.js?

I tried in the following way but its not working:
`var username = '<%=this.Username%>'`

Comment: What isn't working? Has the `UserName` property have a value at the time being used?

Comment: Yes it has. If I write the script in the .ascx, it is working, but in this .js file it doesn't. The username in javascript will have the value "<%=this.Username%>".

Comment: How is the javascript file related to your code file and it's property?

Comment: I think you can't, Javascript is only client-side scripting language

Comment: Do you need to pass only `Username` proeprty value from code-behind to your script, or some properties also? Show how the `MyForm.js` organized

Comment: I have to pass only the Username property. The MyForm.js starts like this:

`(function (Statistics, $) {
    Statistics.MyForm = {
        //#region Model
        model: {
            username: '<%=this.Username%>'
            // ...
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript engine will be unable to resolve the server <%=this.Username%> code in a JS file since the server tags are not part of its specification. These server brackets can be resolved only inside the aspx/ascx files by the ASP.NET engine.

You can create a function in the MyForm.js file that accepts as an argument the ID of the username field getUserName(userName){ return userName;} and call the function from the MyForm.aspx page like this:

[MyForm.aspx]

```
var username = '<%=this.Username%>';
getUserName(userName);
```

[MyForm.js]

```
getUserName(userName)
{
   return userName;
}
```

Comment: Your answer was a bit wrong but I edited it and it works. In MyForm.ascx I wrote a method:
`<script>
    function getUserName() {
        var username = '<%=this.Username%>';
        return username;
    }
</script>`
and in MyForm.js a I called it like: `getUserName()`.

But thanks a lot for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Call the javascript from a server side generic handler file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cogs/awesomejavascript.ashx"></script>
```

Output all of the javascript from the handler file:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext ctx)
{
        ctx.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        StringBuilder bild = New StringBuilder;
        bild.Append("var username = " + this.username);
        ctx.Response.Write(bild.ToString);

}
```

If you're not comfortable with handler files you could use an ascx file.

Comment: Doh! Thanks Patrick, edited but it looks like OP has his answer.

Comment: Yeah. For MVC it was a decent answer. Your file handler idea is good though. +1